# How do I turn email notifications off on the buildfarm?

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With this project http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-hydro-pr2-navigation-teleop_sourcedeb/

I'm getting this error which is spamming my email inbox at about 1 email a minute for the past couple of days.

```
[ros-hydro-pr2-navigation-teleop_sourcedeb] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson7223506363679838700.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rosbuild/hudson/workspace/ros-hydro-pr2-navigation-teleop_sourcedeb/monitored_vcs/scripts/generate_sourcedeb", line 119, in <module>
    rd = Rosdistro(args.rosdistro)
  File "/home/rosbuild/hudson/workspace/ros-hydro-pr2-navigation-teleop_sourcedeb/monitored_vcs/buildfarm/ros_distro.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._index = get_index(get_index_url())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/__init__.py", line 113, in get_index
    yaml_str = load_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdistro/loader.py", line 59, in load_url
    raise URLError(str(e) + ' (%s)' % url)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> (https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml)>
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Description set: 
Sending e-mails to: ros-buildfarm-release@googlegroups.com dash@clearpathrobotics.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

It suggests that the URL can't open the index.yaml which might mean the buildfarm is purposefully shut down which I can respect and see. How do I turn email notifications off?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211721/how-do-i-turn-email-notifications-off-on-the-buildfarm?/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2015-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there is a way to turn off the email notifications from the build farm, and if you're a package maintainer, you probably shouldn't turn them off, because their main purpose is to alert you of real build failures.

At best, you can have your email client filter them out into a folder or something.

I belive the underlying issue here is resolved, but if you see failures like this in the future you may want to email the ros-release list; the buildfarm maintainers may be able to turn emails off on a site-wide basis in events like this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2015-06-19**:
Indeed i have stopped receiving failure emails. Do you know what was wrong/what fixed it?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-06-19**:
https://status.ros.org/incidents/037tvgf4rnfb